# Printing arguments sent to forwardInvocation: subclass of NSProxy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, proxy-classes, objective-c-runtime

I want to intercept messages sent to a proxy object by just printing the selector and arguments. Even if the proxy does not implement them and does not have a target object. Please help. I have looked at several options and Apple docs but they assume that you already know the target object. I want to do this cleanly without memory issues.

```
 @implementation MyProxy

    -(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation*)anInvocation
        {

        // at this point I would

         //like to fetch the arguments and put on an array 
         NSMutableArray *myArgs = .....;
         NSLog(@"Invoking selector %@", theSelector);
         NSLog (myArgs); // this should print me the list of arguments to the method
        }
@end
         // e.g 
            MyProxy *proxy = [[MyProxy alloc] init];
            [proxy SendMeAnyThing: @"hello"]; // this should print me arguments 
        or [proxy add: 12 to: 89 sub: 89]; // should print the arguments
```

Thanks thanks

Answer (score 3):

The arguments are of just about any C type, including Objective-C types, that may be passed to the method.  Thus, they can't be represented in an array.

Note that invoking a method that is not declared anywhere doesn't make any sense.  Quite specifically, the compiler has no idea how to encode the arguments at the call site to make a valid C function call (a method call is really just a C function call to `objc_msgSend()` or a variant).  So, to answer your "any method, even if it doesn't exist" question; no, you can't do that.

You can, however, effectively eliminate all compiler warnings.  If you eliminate all compiler warnings -- all "method foo:bar: has can't be found" type warnings -- then that means the compiler *does* have enough information and you can do whatever the heck you want with a proxy.

Furthermore (as I read more into your question), there is no need to implement any method on the proxy.  A proxy can quite happily forward-into-NSInvocation any method call.  Written correctly, you can have a proxy stand in for any object without issue.

What you need to do is enumerate the arguments using the API of `NSInvocation`, sussing out the types and then decoding each argument accordingly and printing appropriately.

You can grab the number of arguments by invoking `numberOfArguments` on the method signature of the NSInvocation instance (the signature can be had via the `methodSignature` method).

Then, loop through the arguments and call `getArgumentTypeAtIndex:` on the method signature to get the type.  You would then most likely write a `switch()` statement on the type encoding to then call `getArgument:atIndex:` and decode appropriately based on type.

Note that argument 0 is self and argument 1 is _cmd; the SEL of the method that was invoked.